# how to change device wifi network?

Tags: cordova-plugins, android-wifi, wifimanager

Using WifiWizard2 plugin I did following things :-

--> I have connected my laptop to open wifi network(either adhoc or hotspot).

--> I have connected my mobile to open wifi network of my laptop.

--> Was able to change the network of my mobile to required locally available      wifi network using this method - "WifiWizard2.connect(ssid, bindAll, password, algorithm, isHiddenSSID)".

--> **What my requirement is** - will I be able to change the network of my laptop from open network to required locally available wifi networks? which is as done in ring door bell application "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9yTg-iWPy28".